# How to get dependencies list for .so file?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

Let's say i'm having `libFoo.so` compiled for android (arm). I'm not sure what STL implementation it was linked to (there are [options](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html)). How can i get dependencies (as .so list) for it to understand what files i should provide and load using `System.load(...)/loadLibrary(...)`?

Comment: you want to know dependencies of libFoo.so?

Comment: ldd command should help. You can navigate to the android file system using your device command prompt and there execute command ldd libFoo.so. This will list out all the dependencies this dynamic library depends on !

Comment: how can i get it? there is no ldd in neither ndk, nor standalone toolchain. and it can't be found on my mac

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `objdump` tool and filter out the relevant part. In this case, e.g. `arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -p libFoo.so | grep NEEDED`.

The `ldd` tool as suggested normally also does this, but it tries to actually find all the files that would be loaded, and it is not always available in cross-compilation environments.