# Where does an Android app search for shared .so files to load?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

To make this a little more complicated I'm loading a native library I've compiled with ndk and cmake into Unity which will be deployed on Android. This was all working fine until I wanted to link another shared library to the library I was building. Now my library fails to load and I believe it is because it can't find the new shared library. I can say that the new shared library works on its own because I'm using it in another NDK project.

I see that Unity copies the new .so library over to the apps install directory and puts it along with my original library in a /data/appname/lib/arm64 directory. I have also tried installing the library in /system/lib64 but no luck. I have compiled my library without the new shared library and it works, and then only modified cmake to add it back in and my library will no longer load. I have also objdump'd it to make sure it is x64 as well as exported the symbols in case it was corrupted. So I'm wondering, is there a way to find out where my library file is looking?

This is how I include the new shared library in my CmakeList.txt

```
add_library(libusb SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libusb PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION D:/projects/arm64-v8a/libusb1.0.so)
```

where D:\projects\arm64-v8a is the location of the library file on my build machine. I wonder if this is screwing things up. But I use the same syntax in my Android studio Cmake project and I can access the library but I'm sure that's different somehow. Any help is always appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: There may be several pitfalls. One, the imported library may have its own dependencies, which must also be copied to your APK (or AAR). [To check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33719355/192373), run `objdump -p libusb1.so | findstr "NEEDED"`. Second, the imported library may not match the API level of the device. You write you use it in a different project. Does this project run on the same device?

Comment: There should be a system log with error about failing to load the library, it might be useful.

Comment: Alex that was the correct answer, I found it late last night. One of the libraries did indeed have its own NEEDED .so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imported library may have its own dependencies, which must also be copied to your APK (or AAR). [To check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33719355/192373), run `objdump -p libusb1.so | findstr "NEEDED"`.

Answer (score 0):

It will look in the lib/[platform-abi] directory of your app. But there is a list of steps for using prebuilt libraries:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts
Have you checked those?

Comment: Not that specifically because I'm using Cmake.